# Create groups of data with column mean in any given ratio

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset with a column called `value`. I want to create a new category column for this dataset, with three levels `(A,B,C)` such that the ratio of the `average(value)` for each category is in any given ratio (lets say `1.5:1:1.8`).

Any ideas on how to go about this ?

EDIT : I'm including an example here, to make the problem statement clearer.

The dataframe contains multiple columns, one of which (called `value`) is of interest to me.

```
value
  10
  20
  30 
  50
   .
   .
   .
```

I want to create a new column called `category` (A,B,C), which groups these records such that the mean of `value` for category `A` is 1.5 times the mean of `value` for `B`, and the mean of `value` for `C` is 1.8 times 'B'. (The ratios can be different, depending on user input). The final record should look like this :

```
value      Category
 10           A
 20           C
 30           A
 40           C
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68888970/edit) the question and include a sample data from the actual dataframe with the expected result. Please take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You cannot be sure to find a solution, or exact solution. For instance if value is [10, 10, 10], what should you do?

Comment: I am not going for the exact ratios, just approximations. I don't expect to run into edge cases like the one you mentioned. If the ratios are impossible to achieve, something close is good enough

Comment: Also, any requirement on the size of the groups?

Comment: I have about 2k records and I want to partition them into 3 groups. The group size can vary from 300 - 800.